# Can I switch my operating system from Windows 10 to the latest version of Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, backup, operating-systems

I do a lot of 3d rendering and hardware-heavy work on my computer. The hardware itself is in good shape but Windows 10 won't stop freezing programs and takes forever to load files. I've heard that linux distributions are much more lightweight and that they don't crash as much. If this is true, would it be possible to back up my files to Google Drive and switch my operating system to linux (ubuntu)? If anything about this question seems unintelligent or poorly informed, I apologize as I have only recently looked into the subject.

Comment: What do you use for 3d rendering, and what do you mean by hardware-heavy work? You should check that any programs you use for your work are available for Ubuntu, or have alternatives which can replace those you currently use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

First [you should download RUFUS](https://rufus.ie/en/). You need a bootable USB with at least 4 GB of free space or so. Then you will use RUFUS to format the USB and install a bootable image of Ubuntu on the computer. Once you boot from the USB, Ubuntu will give you the option to format your hard drive/SSD, deleting Windows entirely, and you will create a new partition for Ubuntu.

You can use Google Drive to backup your files (as you can just download them onto Ubuntu once finished installing). Just make sure you have enough space for everything. Don't forget the bookmarks on your browser and/or your history if that is important to you.

You may just want to create a second partition on your hard drive for dual booting, however. Just in case Ubuntu does not work out for you, you can just switch back to Windows without losing anything. This is only possible with enough space on your drive (around 40 GB free ideally)